# detect disconnect persistant curl connection

Tags: python, curl

Where should I check for a disconnect in a pycurl persistant connection?

Somewhere in my script the connection is dying/timing out/throwing an error but the script stays open.  I need to detect the problem so I can restart the script.

We are connecting to gnip (a social media data provider)

My code is here: https://gist.github.com/3353033

I've read over the options for libcurl and I read through the php curl_setopts docs because they also leverage libcurl.

```
class Client:  
    time_start = time.time()
    content = ""
    def __init__(self,options):
        self.options = options  
        self.buffer = ""  
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()  
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (USER, PASS))  
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING,'gzip')
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)  
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.on_receive)  
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION,1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt")
        try:
            self.conn.perform()  
        except Exception,e:
            print e.message

    def on_receive(self, data):
        self.buffer += data  

        if data.endswith("\r\n") and self.buffer.strip():  
            if(self.triggered()):
                if(len(self.buffer) != 0 ):
                    try:
                        SaveThread(self.buffer).start()
                    except Exception, e:
                        print "something i commented would have told you there was an error"
                        system.exit(1) 
                self.buffer = ""

    def triggered(self):
        # First trigger based on size then based on time..
        if (len(self.buffer) > SAVE_FILE_LENGTH):
            return True
        time_end = time.time()
        if (((time_end - self.time_start) > ROLL_DURATION)):  #for the time frame 
            self.time_start=time.time()
            return True
        return False
```

edit: i've fixed the gist

Comment: Your gist isn't indented correctly.  I'd also recommend you post your source here.

Comment: @MikeSteder I believe I've fixed the gist and I've copied it here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the above code `system.exit(1)` should be `sys.exit(1)` right?

Other than that do you have any more bare `except` clauses that might be catching the `SystemExit` exception raised by `sys.exit(1)`?

Comment: I'm not looking at the script at the moment, but I am sure that that is not the issue.  We've actually figured out a solution and plan to post it as an answer in the next day or so.  The gist of the problem is that network connectivity issues are a problem.  If the line gets dropped then our provider thinks it should still be sending data down the pipe and it disconnects on their end from a buffer write error, and on our end we are reading from an empty buffer and don't know the connection is dead.  We used a couple of low data speed/timeout options to overcome this and disconnect on low data.

Comment: Hi, we are having similar issues with Gnip. Could you please elaborate on your solution? Our code looks eerily similar to yours. How do you detect low data speed?

Comment: @DeepKapadia set LOW_SPEED_LIMIT and LOW_SPEED_TIME options then you will get an error (28) when network traffic falls below those limits
( see here : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT.html )